# Angular Flex Layout ELI5 'lt' vs 'gt'

Tags: angular, flexbox, angular-flex-layout

I'm experimenting with angular flex layout, and it's really amazing. However, after reading the documentation about a hundred times, I cannot make sense of what the lt and gt prefix mean on the responsive api. Can someone please explain what they mean, what they stand for, and when I might want to use them over the regular xs/sm/md/etc breakpoints?

Comment: less than, greater than ?

Comment: I don't know Angular, but presumably "less than" and "greater than". Looking at the table [here](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Responsive-API), you use `lt-` breakpoints to indicate some size *or smaller*, `gt-` to indicate that size *or larger*, and unprefixed to mean *exactly* some size. Why they didn't go with `lte`/`gte` or `le`/`ge` (for less/greater than *or equal to*), I don't know.

Comment: You might be a genius. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can make your layout a column on mobile devices and rows on everything bigger (greater than).

```html
<div layout-xs="column" layout-gt-xs="row">
...
```